# Switching Sides in Expression

Tags: linear-algebra

Please forgive me if my terminology is incorrect.

What particular rule is used for the following:

(6a - 10c) to -(10c - 6a)

I have looked over a few textbooks but I am not sure why the above is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distributive law, which says that $p(q+r)=(pq+pr)$, applied with $p=−1,q=10c,r=−6a$.

In detail, that gives

\begin{align}
(-1)(10c + (-6a)) 
&= ( (-1)(10c) + (-1)(-6a) ) \text{, by distributive law}\\
&= ( -10c + 6a ) \text{, by rules for negation}\\
&= ( 6a -10c )\text{, by commutative law for addition}
\end{align}